# How to Restore deleted Alerts for a Site collection? [SOS]

Tags: powershell, office-365, csom, alert

So One of our site admins accidentally deleted all the alerts set up by different users on different libraries, folders and documents. We don't have any information on the deleted alerts or what type they were (immediate, weekly, daily etc). We really want all these alerts back.

Is there any way that I could get these alerts back or at least the information about these alerts so that I can create the same alerts again? I can work with CSOM, PowerShell or anything that solves the problem.This is a SharePoint Online site collection. I just want these alerts back! if it is possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can contact Microsoft support. You can ask them to restore a site to a certain point in time within two weeks. That might work if alerts are more important than the content that you will lose.

The alerts are stored in ImmedSubscriptions and SchedSubscriptions tables in the SQL Content Database so it it's not accessible in SharePoint Online and there is no way for you to restore these from some kind of a recycle bin.

Answer (score 0):

As Denis Mentioned, their is no way to restore the Alerts other than asked to Microsoft to restore the Site collection from back date.

That process will overwrite your current site collection and you will lost all the changes since the time of the restore. So be care full with this option, and think about it before asking for restore.

If you really want to restore the alerts then make sure all the updates user made should be saved before the restore. I will try to make the copy of existing site collection to different name & URl, this way you can copy work you will lost during that process.